# Html5 Audio tag doens't refresh content on page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, html, audio-streaming

I'm developing a Radio website, I have created a C# back-end that writes an stream of bytes to the current HTTP response, which is then loaded on the HTML5 **audio** tag.

My problem is: I have for example 5 songs. The desired behavior is that every time the page loads, it should ask the controller for a random song to play. What actually happens is, the first time the page loads, the controller gets called and the song plays normally, but if the user reloads the page, or navigate to a new page and them back to the radio, the **audio** tag instead of calling the controller again, just plays what was downloaded in the audio buffer on the last call, and only when the buffer that was download finishes playing, the audio tag will call the controller, which creates undesired skips, like playing 15 seconds of a song and the starting a new song.

My audio HTML is created dynamically on a "render" method. I tried to make the id random, to try and force the buffer clean, but even with a new id, the tag will still play what was preloaded with the buffer, even if the preload attribute is set to "none". Besides that, I tried sending a random token as a parameter to the c# controller, to try and avoid any caching problems based on the URL, but it didn't work as well.

Heres my controller:

```cs
public void GetStream(StreamType? type, string token)
        {
            var files = this.GetFiles(type);
            int rnd;

            rnd = new Random((int)DateTime.Now.Ticks).Next(0, files.Count);

            using (Stream mystream = files[rnd].OpenRead())
            {
                this.CurrentTrack = files[rnd].Name;

                mystream.Position = 0;
                using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(mystream))
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[mystream.Length];

                    System.Web.HttpResponse response = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response;
                    response.Clear();
                    response.ClearHeaders();
                    response.ClearContent();
                    response.BufferOutput = true;
                    response.ContentType = "audio/mp3";
                    response.AddHeader("Accept-Ranges", "bytes");
                    response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
                    response.AddHeader("Content-Length", mystream.Length.ToString());

                    int bytesRead;
                    while ((bytesRead = reader.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) > 0)
                    {
                        response.OutputStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytesRead);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

And here my JS:

```
audioApp.Initialize = function (type) {
    audioApp.Render(type);
}

audioApp.Render = function (type) {
    type = (type == undefined || type == null || type == "") ? 0 : type;
    var token = audioApp.MakeId();
    var html =  "<div id='divSongName'>"
                + "</div>"
                + "<audio id='" + token + "' autoplay preload='none'>"
                + "     <source src='/Streaming/GetStream/0" + type + "' type='audio/mp3' />"
                + "     <em>Sorry, your browser doesn't support HTML5 audio.</em>"
                + "</audio>"

    $("#divAudioRender").append(html);
}
```

the "Render" method will create the audio element that posts to my back-end.

I've searched a lot on the web for a way to force the audio buffer to be cleaned every time the page refreshes, but I couldn't find anything.

Any help is appreciated,

Thanks!

Comment: Please remove from the question all the non-relevant code and keep **only** whats required

Comment: just removed, left only whats was relevant. thx

Comment: Can you break this down into a page that reproduces what the problem is?  What you're describing really shouldn't happen.

Comment: I've already figured the problem, there's my own answer down the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured out how to solve the problem! On my "Initialize" method that renders the audio element on the DOM, I added these below lines:

```
var audio = $("audio").get(0);
audio.src = "";
audio.src = "/Streaming/GetStream?type=" + type + "'&token=" + audioApp.MakeId();

audio.load();
audio.play();
```

When I changed the source to empty and force the player to load again, it clears the buffer, thus calling the controller on every refresh.

Answer (score -1):

Add a nonce to the URL to make the browser think it's a different file each time.

So, instead of

```
src='/Streaming/GetStream/0" + type + (etc)
```

use

```
var d = new Date();
...
src='/Streaming/GetStream/0" + type + "?version=" + d.getMilliseconds() + (etc)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've already tried that as I said, with the "token" parameter. it's not a cache problem, the problem is that part of the song was downloaded and stored in the audio buffer, which I can't get cleared on refresh, it only clears if I close the page

Comment: Oh I see.  How about a bit of JS on unload, like `audio.currentTime = 9999` to move it to the end?

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the advice, I have tried setting it to 9999, didn't work. I've also tried loading the audio, setting it to 9999, destroying the audio tag and recreating it, but again it just plays whats on the buffer first, and after the buffer ends, it will call the controller =/